# Weird behaviour when merge sorting an array

Tags: c, mergesort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

void DISPLAY(int*, int);

int* MERGE(int*, int,  int* , int,  int* , int ); 
int* MERGESORT(int* , int ); 



int main()
{

    int* array = NULL;
    array = (int*) malloc(7 * sizeof(int) );
    
    array[0] = 10;
    array[1] = 9;
    array[2] = 8;
    array[3] = 57;
    array[4] = 6;
    array[5] = 5;
    array[6] = 24;
    
    printf("\nOriginal array: \n");
    DISPLAY(array, 7);
                
    array = MERGESORT(array, 7);
                
    printf("\n\nResulting array: \n");
    DISPLAY(array, 7);
}

void DISPLAY(int* array, int size)
{
    int i;                                          
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){                  
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}


int* MERGESORT(int *array, int size) {
    if(size < 2) 
        return array; 

    int mid = size / 2;             
    int rightsize = size-mid;   

    int* L = (int*) malloc(mid * sizeof(int));         
    int* R = (int*) malloc((size-mid) * sizeof(int));  
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < mid; i++) 
        L[i] = array[i];                            
    for(i = mid; i < size; i++) 
        R[i-mid] = array[i];                    

    L = MERGESORT(L, mid);                           
    R = MERGESORT(R, size-mid);                     
    array = MERGE(array, size, L, mid, R, rightsize);       
    free(L);                                        
    free(R);                                    
    
    return array;
}


int* MERGE(int *array, int size, int *L, int leftsize,int *R, int rightsize) {
    int i, j, k;
    
    i = 0; 
    j = 0; 
    k = 0;

    while(i < leftsize && j < rightsize)    
    {                   
        if(L[i] < R[j])                     
        {
            array[k] = L[i];                
            i++;                            
        }
        else{                           
            array[k] = R[j];            
            j++;                        
        }
        k++;                        
    }
    while(i < leftsize)                 
    {
        array[k] = L[i];                    
        i++;                                
        k++;                                    
    }
    while(j < rightsize)
    {
        array[k] = L[j];                
        j++;                                
        k++;                            
    }
    
    printf("\nUpdated array: \n");                       
    DISPLAY(array, size);
    return array;
}
```

Hello, I have a problem when I try to perform merge sorting in an array. Some items in the array are printing weird. Every time the arrays get updated, the value gets printed out, but it doesn't work at specific inputs.

When I input small numbers (like 1-2 digits), then the array gets sorted normally.

Sample run of program sorting incorrectly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLg0b.png

Comment: Take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Hint: in `a = malloc(n * sizeof *a)`, you can only reference a[0] through a[n-1].

Comment: In `malloc((size-mid) * sizeof(int))` why not use `rightsize` instead of `size - mid`? Same when you call `MERGESORT(R, size-mid)`. I also recommend you start to use unsigned types for sizes and indexes, preferably `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(j < rightsize)
    {
        array[k] = L[j];                
        j++;                                
        k++;                            
    }
```

should be

```
while(j < rightsize)
        {
            array[k] = R[j];                
            j++;                                
            k++;                            
        }
```

Umm, sorry for wasting time on such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Consider.

```
int* R = (int*) malloc((size-mid) * sizeof(int));
```

(which ought to be written `int *R = malloc((size - mid) * sizeof *R);`)

What is the highest valid index in that array?  Trying to read from (or write to) `R[n]` for n > size - mid - 1 invokes undefined behavior.